Travel vendor wants to back out of agreement
A major cruise line had a cruise on its website, for which some of the rooms were being offered at a price of $0 (plus a deposit).  Numerous people took advantage of this offer, their online deposits were accepted by the cruise line and they received confirmations from the cruise line. A few days later, they received emails saying that the pricing had been an error, and that the cruise line would give them a lesser room on the same cruise without any of the benefits that were stated in the confirmation email.  Can the cruise line simply change or cancel these reservations?

Welcome to the site. Please specify the jurisdiction in which this took place, as laws vary around the world.

Related: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/14409/can-a-vendor-cancel-an-order-due-to-a-pricing-error, https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/16456/taking-advantage-of-seller-pricing-errors, https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/1241/is-it-legal-to-search-for-commerce-sites-listing-items-at-erroneously-low-prices


Can the cruise line simply change or cancel these reservations?

Yes, pretty much everywhere.
A contract requires consideration which is what which party will get out of a contract (a contract is a bilateral affair, you can't have a contract where a party gets nothing).
If the consideration is illusory or nonexistant, it can be found unconscionable and the contract would not be enforcable.

In france

Un contrat à titre onéreux est nul lorsque, au moment de sa formation, la contrepartie convenue au profit de celui qui s'engage est illusoire ou dérisoire.

(Translation mine)

A contract for valuable consideration is void when, at the time of its formation, the consideration agreed for the benefit of the contracting party is illusory or derisory.


In united-states, the unilateral mistake of facts affirmative defense would allow, in most cases, for the contract to be unconscionable and therefore unenforceable

california civil code 1577 reads :

MISTAKE OF FACT. Mistake of fact is a mistake, not caused by the neglect of a legal duty on the part of the person making the mistake, and consisting in:

An unconscious ignorance or forgetfulness of a fact past or present, material to the contract; or,

Belief in the present existence of a thing material to the contract, which does not exist, or in the past existence of such a thing, which has not existed.



Note that, for such a defense to prevail in California, a party must have used the mistake of facts to take advantage of another party (which is the case here, nobody would take a $0 + deposit cruise as real and would have knowingly taken advantage of the other party (the cruise line)) :

However, such a unilateral mistake may not invalidate a contract without a showing that the other party to the contract was aware of the mistaken belief and unfairly utilized that mistaken belief in a manner enabling him to take advantage of the other party.” (Meyer v. Benko)


You don't think taking a zero dollar price is taking advantage?

@Mimedfp This is what I said, taking a 0$ price is taking advantage

@Mimedfp a 0 dollar item has no consideration and can not form a contract on its own
